# Facing android compile errors

Tags: android, gradle

Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1
Add Google Maven repository and sync project
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app, easy-android-splash-screen

Answer (score 0):

Add this on your build.gradle file

```
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
```

Comment: bundle of thanks i was trying to solve this issue since yesterday,

Comment: what is usage of this can u please explain

Comment: they contain some libraries for android projects, in your case Maven Central repository is some obsolete and you can replace it for jcenter and google repositories. If you want to know more, check this https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter